# Generator with condition in F#

Tags: f#

if you know, how I can write generator with condition in F# - tell me please!) something like that:

```
let res = [for i in 1..5 if i % 2 = 0 then i]
printfn "%A" res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost on the right track.

```
let res = 
    [   
        for i in 1..5 do 
            if i % 2 = 0 then 
                yield i
    ]
```

The feature you're looking for is [list comprehensions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists#Using_List_Comprehensions).
This is similar to `yield return` in C#. The same comprehensions are available for `seq` and `Array`.

Comment: From [F# 4.7](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-4-7/) the `yield` keyword is implicit so you should never actually need to include it.